# Why are spaces being converted to question marks in this script?

Tags: terminal, bash, mp3

I'm attempting to modify a bash script someone else wrote, and while it's off to an okay start, I'm running into issues.

For any files that contain a space, the spaces are being converted to question marks (e.g. `20-21 HS Scales Warmup.m4a` is becoming `20-21?HS?Scales?Warmup.mp3`). I can tell from the logging, that it’s putting in newlines where it shouldn’t but I don’t know how to get that to stop.

The script’s source is:

```
PAH=${1?Error: no name given}

FLNAME=$(basename $PAH)
CLPAH=${PAH%/*}

cd $CLPAH

NFLNAME=${FLNAME%%.*}

/opt/homebrew/bin/ffmpeg -n -i "$PAH" -codec:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 2 "$NFLNAME.mp3" && echo "Finished! File can be found at $CLPAH/$NFLNAME" || echo "Fail. There is already a File named $NFLNAME in the same directory"
```

It’s an Alfred command that I’ve modified from [someone else’s workflow](https://github.com/samuelspagl/alfred_ffmpeg)

Comment: If you run the script directly in bash, does it work?

Answer (score 2):

```bsh
FLNAME=$(basename $PAH)
```

is missing quotes

```bsh
FLNAME=$(basename "$PAH")
```

Others are missing quotes too.
Make sure you quote all your variables everywhere.

Comment: Thanks, this solved it! I had tried
`FLNAME=$("basename $PAH")` 
but not 
`FLNAME=$(basename "$PAH")`
Turns out that fixes it

Comment: Don't forget to quote the var in the `cd` command too.